# 404 error when moving LWC to Community

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, lwc-wire-adapter, wire

So I have made an LWC which is working perfectly on a test App page. Now I have changed the metadata and added in some code to pull a variable from the url so that it can be used in a community. I have checked all permissions and it all looks good (the community had all relevant permissions already as this is a new version of an existing page), but I keep getting the following error from the initial record wire:

errorCode: "NOT_FOUND"

message: "The requested resource does not exist"

statusCode: 404

When I know this exists as it works in the App Page and I can see the record in the other tab.

```
export default class userLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api recordId;
    @track isSpinner = false;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.isSpinner = true;
    }

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    handleWiredBooking(result){
        this.isSpinner = false;
        this.booking = result;
        console.log('result==>'+result);
        const {error,data} = result;
        if (error){
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error loading Booking',
                message: error.body.message,
                variant: 'error'
            }),);
            console.warn(error);
        } else if (data){
            console.log('data==>'+data);
            this.record = data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you publish the community after adding the page?

Comment: Yes I am getting the error on the Community page I have added with the LWC on, after publishing. I can see the title of the card and the console logs so I know its running the LWC on the Community Page.